# Jenkins/Maven job - running the test suite twice?

Tags: maven, jenkins, webdriver, testng

I have 2 tests, in a Maven project and I have Xvfb starting along the tests.
What I want to achieve is the following:
- start Xvfb so the tests run headless
- run the tests.

But what happens, when I start the job is:
- The tests run and fail, because they can't find a display, because xvfb isnt running
- Xvfb starts
- The tests run again

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pragmaticqa.tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>functionalTests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>functionalTests</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <displayProps>target/selenium/display.properties</displayProps>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- <pluginManagement> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xvfb</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xvfb</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <display>:20</display>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>selenium</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <!-- <display.props>${displayProps}</display.props> -->
                        <!-- <display>:21</display> -->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <!-- </pluginManagement> -->
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my testng.xml (I dont know whether it has some role in a maven project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<test name="NewTest" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="AppTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="aNewPlaceIsBornAndThenEdited" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="AppTest2">
            <methods>
                <include name="twoUsersSignUp" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

My github repository consists of the whole maven project with a target folder, where some copies of the test classes are always stored.

My jenkins job settings:

- asksing for a git repository, link provided
- Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built - this is on, but it doesnt make a difference whether its on or off
- Maven options: -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx256m - this has also nothing to do with anything

console output:

```
Building in workspace /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@7cd2da43
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision ac0ccfc8f2d3ab2a8c079cddec073c03dfb57dce (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Commencing build of Revision ac0ccfc8f2d3ab2a8c079cddec073c03dfb57dce (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision ac0ccfc8f2d3ab2a8c079cddec073c03dfb57dce (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xmx256m -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp /mnt/www/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.3.jar:/mnt/www/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /mnt/www/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.0.5 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.28.jar /mnt/www/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.3.jar 60610

<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Executing Maven:  -B -f /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/pom.xml install

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building functionalTests 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ functionalTests ---

[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ functionalTests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ functionalTests ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ functionalTests ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) @ functionalTests ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: cannot open display: :20
Error: cannot open display: :20

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
    at com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppTestData.setUp(AppTestData.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:117)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: cannot open display: :20
Error: cannot open display: :20

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
    at com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppTestData.setUp(AppTestData.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:117)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 93.916 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2

[JENKINS] Recording test results

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ functionalTests ---

[INFO] Building jar: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:xvfb (xvfb) @ functionalTests ---

[INFO] Starting Xvfb...
[INFO] Using display: :20
[INFO] Using Xauthority file: /tmp/Xvfb450292168912752014.Xauthority
Deleting: /tmp/Xvfb450292168912752014.Xauthority
xauth:  file /tmp/Xvfb450292168912752014.Xauthority does not exist
Launching Xvfb
Waiting for Xvfb...
[INFO] Redirecting output to: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/selenium/xvfb.log

Xvfb started
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- selenium-maven-plugin:2.3:start-server (selenium) @ functionalTests ---
Launching Selenium Server
Waiting for Selenium Server...
[INFO] Including display properties from: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/selenium/display.properties
[INFO] User extensions: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/selenium/user-extensions.js

08:51:30,509 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b12
08:51:30,510 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] OS: Linux 3.2.0-31-virtual amd64
08:51:30,521 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] v2.21.0, with Core v2.21.0. Built from revision 16551
08:51:30,793 INFO  [org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer] RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
08:51:30,795 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer] Version Jetty/5.1.x
08:51:30,796 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
08:51:30,797 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
08:51:30,797 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/,/]

08:51:30,951 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@6a8c436b
08:51:30,951 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
08:51:30,957 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener] Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
08:51:30,957 INFO  [org.openqa.jetty.util.Container] Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1bc74f37
08:51:31.693 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
Selenium Server started
[INFO] [INFO] Surefire report directory: /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/surefire-reports

[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default) @ functionalTests ---

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 319.362 sec <<< FAILURE!
[JENKINS] Recording test results
Results :

Failed tests: 
  aNewPlaceIsBornAndThenEdited(com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppTest)
  twoUsersSignUp(com.pragmaticqa.tests.AppTest2)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0


[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ functionalTests ---
[INFO] Installing /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/pragmaticqa/tests/functionalTests/1.0-SNAPSHOT/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/pragmaticqa/tests/functionalTests/1.0-SNAPSHOT/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7:11.329s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 02 08:56:53 UTC 2013

[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/pom.xml to /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/modules/com.pragmaticqa.tests$functionalTests/builds/2013-08-02_08-49-31/archive/com.pragmaticqa.tests/functionalTests/1.0-SNAPSHOT/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/workspace/target/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /mnt/www/jenkins/jobs/Integration tests/modules/com.pragmaticqa.tests$functionalTests/builds/2013-08-02_08-49-31/archive/com.pragmaticqa.tests/functionalTests/1.0-SNAPSHOT/functionalTests-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped

Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like at some stage the tests are being run and we have the chance to stop them from running again, by configuring skip to true

```
     <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
     </execution>
```

Comment: I don't think that works. From the docs: "Set this to "true" to bypass unit tests entirely. Its use is NOT RECOMMENDED, especially if you enable it using the "maven.test.skip" property, because maven.test.skip disables both running the tests and compiling the tests. Consider using the skipTests parameter instead."

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am using emma code coverage tool by configuring it in my pom.xml. So my test suite gets executed twice. once by emma tool and once by sure fire. Hence, I have skipped test execution by sure fire.